# Как получить содержимое текстового поля (input) с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть форма обратной связи:

```
<form id="contactForm">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="h4">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" class="h4">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваш Е-mail" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message" class="h4">Сообщение</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Введите сообщение"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" id="submit" type="submit" onclick="SendMail();" value="Отправить">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Есть JS:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
 var name = $(this).val();
});
$('#email').keyup(function() {
 var email = $(this).val();
});
$('#message').keyup(function() {
  var message = $(this).val();
});

function SendMail() {

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../inc/mail.php",
   data: { name: name, email: email, message: message}
}).done(function( msg ) {
     alert(msg);
  });
}
```

Нужно получить данные из полей input.
Но при работе переменные name, email и message определяются как *undefined*.
Где ошибка? Не могу понять...

Comment: ошибка в том, что это переменные **объявлены локально** в обработчиках событий

Comment: @Grundy блин, спасибо большое!